# Bootstrap Navigation bar toggle button not Responding

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

When I shrink the window and click the nav toggle button it doesn't work. Button doesn't respond. What would be the problem here could anyone tell me please?

```
    <nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="javascript:void(0)">
                <h3 class="my-heading ">SKEWED</h3>
            </a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="fa fa-bars mfa-white"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
                <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#home">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#overview">Overview</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#team"> Team</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#testimonials">Testimonial</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#blog">Blog</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#contact">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! data-target is targeting wrong id `navbarResponsive` is id for menu but you are targeting `data-target="#navbarNav"`

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my mistake :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Where is this id that you give to data-target="#navbarNav" .. you are not using this ID anywhere then how the toggle works.. 

 <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
```

change it accordingly.. because the target and the ID is different.

[image: You are using Two Different ID's for data-Target and the Div]

Answer (score 0):

I have create a fiddle for you, copied from Bootstrap website. Kindly refer [Bootstrap website](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/) for more.

In your example you are targeting `data-target="#navbarNav"`. But your `<div class="collapse navbar-collapse"` id is `"navbarResponsive"`. Put the same `id` to in `data-target`. This may solve your issue.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="javascript:void(0)">
      <h3 class="my-heading ">SKEWED</h3>
    </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="fa fa-bars mfa-white"></span>
                show
            </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#home">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#overview">Overview</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#team"> Team</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#testimonials">Testimonial</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#blog">Blog</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#contact">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Welcome to stack overflow your (data-target="#myNavbar") should be same for (id="myNavbar") hope this will be helpfull...